# Delete a whole List in C++

Tags: c++, list

I have found online a very simple List class. In my program I have created a list of a specific type and used it for some calculations. Now I want to use the same list (same type of list) and use it for other things. To make things clearer:

```
List<Vertex*> vertices;
List<Triangle*> triangles;
```

I am adding info in these lists using two functions:

```
void AddVertex(List<Vector> &vertex)
void AddFaces(List<triangle_data> &f)
```

These are the two basic lists I'm using. Now I want to use the same lists for other vertices and triangles (different model). So how am I supposed to "delete" everything inside the two lists and use them with different vertices and triangles?

This is the typical list.h I am using:

```
template <class Type> class List {
public:
            List(int s=0);
            ~List();
    void    allocate(int s);
    void    SetSize(int s);
    void    Pack();
    void    Add(Type);
    void    AddUnique(Type);
    int     Contains(Type);
    void    Remove(Type);
    void    DelIndex(int i);
    Type *  element;
    int     num;
    int     array_size;
    Type    &operator[](int i){assert(i>=0); assert(i<num); return element[i];}
}
```

Comment: You *found* a list online that you're using? Why not use `std::list<>`? (Which should rather be `std::vector<>`.)

Comment: First of all, I wouldn't call it just "List" - most (C++) programmers would think that it's some kind of linked list.

Comment: delete [] element; Or am I misunderstanding your question? Btw, why use ints for indexing? Use unsigned ints.

Comment: well it looks like this list class doesn't have a clear method.  you're screwed.  switch to std::list, or, otherwise, you have to do *while (list.num) list.DelIndex(0);* or write your own clear method which just does *num=0;*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.  Your *List* class is really a vector class.

You can either:

(1) replace it with *std::vector* and then call *std::vector::clear* on it,

(2) add a *Clear* method to your *List* class as follows:

```
void List::Clear(bool resetSize /* = false */) {
    num = 0;
    if (resetSize) {
         delete [] element; element=0; array_size = 0;
    }
}
```

then call *Clear* appropriately.

or

(3) you can do this:

```
while (list.num) list.DelIndex(list.num-1);
```

This is assuming that you have a *List* instance called *list*.

And here are the commentaries:

(1) is preferred because it is canonical and easy for the next guy to read your code.  (2) is OK if you absolutely don't want to change your code.  (3) is OK if you're really lazy and don't care about performance (or if you can't change the *List* class for whatever reason -- e.g. you only have access to the header).

Comment: You forgot to reset `element` to 0 after the `delete` which will definitely cause a lot of trouble... And even then we can't be sure this would be correct since we don't know the implementation details of the other methods.

Answer (score 4):

I would use an STL container like std::list or std::vector and use the [clear()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/clear/) member function.

Comment: My whole program (2500 lines+) currently uses this list and its functions so I cannot just switch to the std::list. Any other advice?

Comment: Find & replace? I did that with a file (and a typedef) of more than 9000 lines pretty effortlessly.

Comment: Just change to std::vector (which is what your `List` class really is) even if that must cost you some refactoring time. This `List` class is awful, it doesn't even have proper data encapsulation (everything is public) so anyone can mess with its internals! Ewww...

Comment: Replacing your list now with std::vector or std::list, which with find and replace operations should take only a few painless mintutes, will save you heaps of trouble in the future when you want to re-use your code in other projects, expand functionality etc. And it'll put you on the path of using standard solutions instead of unsupported unmaintained "stuff you find online" - which is something you should avoid doing whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to adopt `std::vector<>`, but I have read from you that your code relies heavily on that "`List`". Actually that is not entirely a problem, you can "transform" your `List<>` in `std::vector<>` this way (not the best way, that's true):

```
template <class Type> class List {
public:
    List(int s=0)
        { v.capacity( s ); }
    ~List()
        { v.clear(); }
    void    allocate(int s)
        { v.reserve( s ); }
    void    SetSize(int s)
        { v.resize( s ); }
    void    Pack()
        {}
    void    Add(Type x)
        { v.push_back( x ); }
    void    AddUnique(Type)
        {}
    int Contains(Type x)
        { std::vector::iterator it = find( v.begin(), v.end(), x );
          return ( it - v.begin() );
        }
    void    Remove(Type x)
        { int pos = Contains( x ); if ( pos < Size() ) { DelIndex( pos ); } }
    void    DelIndex(int i)
        { v.erase( v.begin() + i ); }
    Type    &operator[](int i)
        {assert(i>=0); assert(i<num); return element[i];}
    Type    &operator[](int i) const
        {assert(i>=0); assert(i<num); return element[i];}
    unsigned int Size() const
        { return v.size(); }
private:
    std::vector<T> v;
};
```

Well, you get the idea. I have left some of them empty since I don't know exactly what they do.

About your question, you are apparently storing pointers to `Triangles` and `Vertex`. If the only pointers to that objects are the ones in the list object, then you should run over the list in order to delete each one, *before* removing the entire vector.

```
template <typename T>
void ClearList(List<T> &l)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < l.Size(); ++i) {
        delete l[ i ];
    }

    l.Clear();
}
```

Hope this helps.